# Calling pl/sql function with mybatis 3

Tags: oracle, plsql, mybatis

I have a function that returns a boolean value in pl/sql. I have tried to 
get directly that boolean value without success, so now I'm trying to convert it to  string (I do not want to modify the database):

```
<parameterMap id="publicObject"   type="map">
<parameter javaType="java.lang.Object" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="OUT" property="result" /> 
<parameter javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN" property="id" /> 
</parameterMap>     

<select id="isPublicObject" parameterMap="publicObject" statementType="CALLABLE">

   <![CDATA[
    {
    declare
    v_bool BOOLEAN := TRUE;
    begin
    v_bool := PACKNAME.STF$IS_PUBLIC_OBJECT(#{id});
    #{result} := CASE WHEN v_bool THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END;
    end;
    }
    ]]>

</select>
```

Then I get this exception:
"Error querying database. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #2 with JdbcType OTHER. Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111 ####

This code works correctly in the database:

```
declare
    v_bool BOOLEAN := TRUE;
    v_str  VARCHAR2(5);
begin
   v_bool := PACKNAME.STF$IS_PUBLIC_OBJECT('000000');
   v_str := CASE WHEN v_bool THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END;
   dbms_output.put_line('result:');
   dbms_output.put_line(v_str); 
end;
```

Comment: MyBatis User Guide: `parameterMap` - "this is a deprecated approach to referencing an
external parameterMap. Use inline parameter
mappings and the parameterType attribute." See example here: http://mybatis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/refcursor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote `parameterType` & `Map` example. It works on my test data.

XML:

```
<update id="isPublicObject" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
    declare
        v_bool BOOLEAN := TRUE;
    begin
        v_bool := PACKNAME.STF$IS_PUBLIC_OBJECT(#{id});
        #{result,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT} := CASE WHEN v_bool THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END;
    end;
</update>
```

Mapper:

```
public interface PLSQLMapper {
    public void isPublicObject(Map<String, Object> parameterMap);
}
```

Main:

```
PLSQLMapper mapper = session.getMapper(PLSQLMapper.class);

Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameterMap.put("id", 1);
mapper.isPublicObject(parameterMap);
System.out.println("result: " + parameterMap.get("result"));
```

Comment: Well this is working for me, the main difference with my code are the curly braces. If I put them it does not work so I made a mess with that trying a lot of things, but the main point where the braces. Thank you!

Comment: @HernanDiaz, I'm using 3.2.3-SNAPSHOT (but i checked it with 3.1 - it works too), i am prefer `parameterType` (and Map or my own object) because `parameterMap` is [depracated](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html). I am glad to help you.

Comment: PS: can you tell me why did you know that you should not use braces{} ? I have seen some examples of code and they always use them

Comment: As far as I know, brackets is SQL92 escape syntax, Oracle syntax is begin-end block without braces. I don't seen examples with begin-end and braces. I could be wrong but I'm new to oracle.

Comment: Awesame!! You saved my life =)

Answer (score -1):

The #{} syntax can only be used for parameter substitution. It is not a variable that gets set after the execution of the PL/SQL. It can only be set before the prepared statement is built.

One way of going forward would be to use stored procedure and use an OUT param to get your result out.

Comment: I'm doing it like that now for testing, but I don't want to change the database only for this in production as several projects depend on it