# Error occurred while setting parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, mybatis, callable

I'm trying to call a procedure with MyBatis.

This is the procedure signature:

```
PROCEDURE pr_start(io_calc    IN OUT TYPE_CALC,
                   in_restart BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
                   in_user    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL);
```

It's in a package named `PACKAGE_PP`.

This is how `TYPE_CALC` is declared:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_CALC AS OBJECT (
    modelField   VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),
    sysField     VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),
    hexField     VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)
);
```

This is my XML mapping:

```
<select id="pr_start" 
    statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="map">
    {
        exec PACKAGE_PP.pr_start(
            #{io_calc,mode=INOUT,jdbcType=STRUCT,jdbcTypeName=TYPE_CALC},
            #{in_restart,mode=IN,jdbcType=BOOLEAN,jdbcTypeName=BOOLEAN},
            #{in_user,mode=IN,jdbcType=VARCHAR,jdbcTypeName=VARCHAR2}
        )
    }
</select>
```

(**p.s.** I also tried with `call` instead of `exec`, it produces the same error)

My java mapper:

```
public interface PackagePPMapper {
    Object pr_start(Map<String, Object> param);
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
Object[] typeCalcArr = new Object[]{"A", "s", "0xD"};

WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor wsn = new WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor();
Connection connection = wsn.getNativeConnection(session.getConnection()); //session is a SqlSession (properly initialized)
StructDescriptor descriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("TYPE_CALC", connection);
STRUCT typeCalc = new STRUCT(descriptor, connection, typeCalcArr);

Map<String, Object> parametersMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parametersMap.put("io_calc", typeCalc);
parametersMap.put("in_restart", restart);
parametersMap.put("in_user", user);

getMapper(session).pr_start(parametersMap);
```

StackTrace:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 6
### The error may exist in com/jsfproj/mybatis/xmlmapper/PackagePPMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.jsfproj.mybatis.PackagePPMapper.pr_start-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: {    exec PACKAGE_PP.pr_start(     ?,     ?,     ?    )   }
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 6
```

What am I missing? Should procedures be called in other ways?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Could you try using a SQL datatype like NUMBER instead of a BOOLEAN in your package procedure?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I had that guess too, and I tried changing the `BOOLEAN` to `NUMBER`, then I changed the mapping to accept a `NUMBER` (with `#{in_restart,mode=IN,jdbcType=NUMERIC,jdbcTypeName=NUMBER}`), and passing `1` instead of `true`, but unfortunately nothing changed, I got the exact same error

Comment: I don't know about mybatis, but `EXEC ...` is usually not valid Oracle syntax for calling a stored procedure (unless you're using SQL/Plus). Try wrapping it in an anonymous PL/SQL block instead `begin PACKAGE_PP.pr_start(...); end;`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859123/calling-pl-sql-function-with-mybatis-3 for an example.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Tried, same error. Anyway, yes I'm using SQL Plus, so exec is valid

Answer (score 0):

Remove surrounding braces to [stop JDBC driver from trying to interpret query as SQL92-compatible query](http://oracle.su/docs/11g/java.112/e10589/apxref.htm#i1005081):

```
<select id="pr_start" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="map">
  call PACKAGE_PP.pr_start(
            #{io_calc,mode=INOUT,jdbcType=STRUCT,jdbcTypeName=TYPE_CALC},
            #{in_restart,mode=IN,jdbcType=BOOLEAN,jdbcTypeName=BOOLEAN},
            #{in_user,mode=IN,jdbcType=VARCHAR,jdbcTypeName=VARCHAR2}
        )
</select>
```

Also it's possible to use native Oracle syntax:

```
<select id="pr_start" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="map">
  begin
    PACKAGE_PP.pr_start(
      #{io_calc,mode=INOUT,jdbcType=STRUCT,jdbcTypeName=TYPE_CALC},
      #{in_restart,mode=IN,jdbcType=BOOLEAN,jdbcTypeName=BOOLEAN},
      #{in_user,mode=IN,jdbcType=VARCHAR,jdbcTypeName=VARCHAR2}
    );
  end;
</select>
```

Comment: You need to use typeHandler for setting the jdbcType="ARRAY"